# Show that $A^+ = A^T (A A^T)^{-1}$ if rank of $A$ is $m$

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

### Try:

if rank(A) = m, then $AA^T$ is a square matrix of size $m$ so the inverse exists. Notice that to show (a), we can multiply both sides by A (left and right) to obtain

$$ A = AA^T (AA^T)^{-1} A $$

So, if we can show this, then we are done. but the above is true since $AA^T (AA^T)^{-1} = I_m $

The second part is also same idea. Multiply by $A$ but only from left to obtain

$$ A A^+ = AA^T (AA^T)^{-1} = I_m $$

Is this a correct solution? I feel like it is too simple. Am I missing something?

Comment: What you miss is that, *a priori* the pseudo-inverse is not unique. You have correctly verified that $A^T(AA^T)^{-1}$ is a pseudo-inverse, but is it possible that there is another pseudo-inverse? It's your task to eliminate that possibility, namely to show that if $rank(A) = m$ then there is only one pseudo-inverse, which is the given one.

Comment: @WhatsUp the question itself seems to awkwardly avoid that issue: it says, "**The** [Moore]-Penrose inverse... is defined as **a** matrix satisfying...".  It is not clear whether they are asking for a proof of uniqueness.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes, my guess is that this comes from some exercise sheet and is not very seriously written. Obviously for $A = 0$ all matrices are pseudo-inverses.

Comment: @James could you tell us where this exercise comes from?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse I lol at Monroe... But indeed I was wrong about the $A = 0$ example. The uniqueness is proved in a link in that wiki page.